# Assigning numeric key to a JS object, does vm create keys from 0 to that value thinking that I'm indexing into an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was told that assigning numeric keys to Javascript objects is a bad idea because the VM will think it an array index and allocate some memory for as many elements as 0 to numeric-key-chosen. All these will be initialized to undefined but still take up a little bit of memory, leading to the object's memory footprint being quite large.

I've read that objects cannot, in fact have keys that are not strings or symbols. So what's really happening?

Comment: Your thinking of arrays..  doing `var a = {1000000: "hello"}` does not create 1 million empty keys.  But doing `var a = []; a[1000000] = "hello"` would..

Comment: @Keith Even that will create a sparse array and no consume millions of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If we do not mean some hidden engine optimization that can be messed up, it seems no allocation happens neither in arrays nor in objects:

```js
> const ar = [];
undefined
> ar[10] = 10
10
> 10 in ar
true
> '10' in ar
true
> 11 in ar
false
> 9 in ar
false
> '9' in ar
false
> const obj = {};
undefined
> obj[10] = 10
10
> 10 in obj
true
> '10' in obj
true
> 11 in obj
false
> 9 in obj
false
> '9' in obj
false
>
```

However, sparse array are slower in V8 (see https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds). I am not aware of any sideeffects for objects with numeric keys though (but see [this section](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#prefer-arrays-over-array-like-objects) in the same article).